# How to access header and property from callee in ASynch Route in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have Apache Camel Route which listens to ActiveMQ queue. During the processing, at one point, route sets the header and property on the exchange.

Now during the integration testing, we want to check the value of the header and property.

The question is, how do we access these two things ie. header and property.

I have tried using the producerTemplate's asyncRequestBody/asyncRequestBodyAndHeader etc. With Future object I can access Exchange, however, I am not able to access the header and property set on the exchange.

I have made sure that the route is InOut type.

Comment: Can you add the route code, including where the headers/properties are set and then read?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the exchange, can you not just use exchange.getProperty(name) to get the property you're looking for?

I have set properties in my route:

`<setProperty propertyName="sampleProperty">
  <simple>${body}</simple>
</setProperty>`

and retrieve them later using {property.sampleProperty}

Comment: In my case the route is asynchronous i.e. it reads from queue. And I am thinking thats why when i do exchange.getProperty(name), it returns null